# is it bad practice to call another interface method from a interface on a java interface?

Tags: java

For example i have an interface as following:

```
interface Test  {
    void a();
    void b();
}

class TestImpl implements Test {
    public void a() {
        // Do something
    }

    public void b() {
        // Do something
        a();
    }
}
```

i think this is bad practice. is it true? or is there any theory on this?

Comment: Why do you think this is a bad practice? It's perfectly valid.

Comment: This code isn't valid in Java; you didn't specify return types for the methods, and `class` should not have a capital `C`. Also, your question cannot really be answered in a useful way unless you explain why you think it would be bad practice.

Comment: Please compile your code before posting.

Comment: You have an interface and you have a class that implements it. This code is absolutelly valid. The interface allows you to declare the methods and in the class you just have to implement them. PS : void is not returning anything technically ... you can print a text for example... Is there a specific reason for you to use an interface ?

Comment: sorry i just want to take an example here. the problem here is that it may break the single responsibility rule as i would imagine. Method B will also have the function that A has, is it good?

Comment: Method b is separate from method a. Why would you think them the same?

Answer (score 0):

This not bad practice. For example check the following use cases.

```
interface Test  {
   void bigTask();
   void validateBigTask();
   void performBigTask();
}
```

In this case you might subdivide your big task for clarity and readability.

Comment: I wouldn't expose those as part of the interface though, they're implementation details.  (Although your sentiment does have several other valid examples.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bad practice.
Look at the below example:

```
interface Task {
    boolean preConditionTask();
    void executeTask();
    boolean postConditionTask();
}

public class TaskImpl implements Task {

    boolean preConditionTask() {
        //Some logic.
    }

    boolean postConditionTask() {
        //Some logic.
    }

    void executeTask() {
        if (!preConditionTask()) {
            //Log or throw.
        }

        //Some task logic.

        if (!postConditionTask()) {
            //Log or throw.
        }
    }
}
```

You have a contract that every task must implement.
The contract tell the implementer that every task have pre, post and execute logic.